# Google Calendar API V3 Service Account

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using the Google .net Client library to access the Google Calendar API. I need to develop an application that creates calendar events and post them to users.

This is is a  Server to Server Application, so I have create a Service account and using that to send invites. The Attendee response to these event created are updated when the responses are submitted from a web browser, but when response from any mail client likes outlook the response is being sent as email to the service account email id which is a dummy email id.  How Can I Assign a valid email account to Service Account Email Id, so that I can use this valid email to create events.

Answer (score 1):

The service account email address is the account id identifying the service account itself.    You cant change the service accounts email address.

The only work around I can think of for you would be to create a dummy gmail account and to use oauth2 instead you can authenticate this account once get the refresh token and have your server to server application run though that.  The main drawback to this is if for some weird reason the refresh token becomes invalid (Rare but can happen) you will need to re-authenticate your server application.

Anwser: No you cant change the email address of the service account.